# combine multiple words documents into one document

Tags: python, ms-word, document

I have multiple documents with following names: auto_1.docx, auto_2.docx, auto_3.docx in one folder(dir) and I was able to combine these with following codes.

```
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
from docx import Document
master = Document(auto_1.docx)
composer = Composer(master)
doc1 = Document(auto_2.docx)
composer.append(doc1)
doc2 = Document(auto_3.docx)
composer.append(doc2)
composer.save(dir)
```

and I wonder whether there is a way to shorten this as I might end up with 100s line if I have 100s documents

Comment: Combining Word documents that may use different page layouts, headers, footers, Style definitions, etc., is way more complicated than you envisage. For a comprehensive VBA solution, see: https://www.msofficeforums.com/word-vba/43339-combine-multiple-word-documents.html

Answer (score 0):

```py
from pathlib import Path
from docxcompose.composer import Composer
from docx import Document

composer = None

for docx_file in Path('your folder').glob('*.docx'):

    try:
        composer.append(Document(docx_file))
    except AttributeError:
        composer = Composer(Document(docx_file))

composer.save(dir)
```

Note: if you get an error message that indicates that pathlike objects are not support, wrap the Path object into a `str` call, e.g. `composer = Composer(Document(str(docx_file)))`.